# City based controller function in url CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am working on a site in CodeIgniter.

I want my site users to select the city from a drop-down and then the content to be displayed on the basis of that city. For this I have two issues.

1) How can I add a new parameter to the URL segment. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647095/codeigniter-adding-parameters-to-url) . Is it ok to create city as controller? but then how should I create the current controllers? If so,

2) Problem is I have already worked on all controllers.

Guide me on how should I proceed.

Comment: You can create single controller and pass country name posted by dropdown as controller function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the uri segments as parameters to your controller.

http://YOUR_URL.com/index.php/city/get/zurich

```
<?php
class City extends CI_Controller {

        public function get($city)
        {
                echo $city;
        }
}
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

**Edit**

Just to give you an idea:

First remove the index.php from the URL:

create the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# When CI is in a subfolder use this line instead
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Open the file `/application/config/config.php` and search for the line

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

and change it to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Open the file `/application/config/routes.php` and add this line to the other rules

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "$2/$3/$1";
```

And the controller looks like this.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class City extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($city)
    {
        echo $city;
    }
}
```

So I'm just changing the order of the segments. 2 = Class, 3 = Method, 1 = parameters.

Comment: Thanks. But I need something like `http://myurl/zurich/somecontroller/somefunction`

Comment: Alright, @SachinStellen. I just updated my answer. It's just a idea how you could do it. Maybe it's not the perfect way. But just try it out. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this.
-first tell me how u send request after selecting a city from dropdown.
-anyways i will tell you ,first add jquery 'change' event to dropdown list and on change you have to get the current value of the dropdown list as
e.g

```
$('#idOfDropDownlist').on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    //now send a ajax request to controller to get information about city.
    $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>ControllerName/methodName/"+value,
    success:function(response){
     console.log(response);
}
});
});

//---- your controller's method for getting this request will be like.

class ControllerName .....{
public function methodName($city = ''){
//--- here you got the city name,so do whatever u want with......
}
}
```