# how to pull out or view data from database in interface using Codeigniter and java

Tags: database, codeigniter

I'm new programmer and learning how to get data from database using Codeigniter and Java. Currently doing a system for user to post comment on different post. Below each post will have "post comment" button. For example, there were several post on a page. When a user click on button "Post a Comment" on A post, it will link to another page posting the comment, but how to make the page know that it post comment on A post. After post the comment, the database will show like user post the comment at A post. Any website for me to refer or study about it? thank you...

Comment: You should add some code, otherwise a lot of user will vote down your question.

Comment: Agreed with Deniz put some code or else you will have a many down votes, also adding code will help us know how to help you

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a post with id (primary key, generated by the database) 37. Then, the button or link just below the post should have a link to something like:

'index.php/comment/newcomment/37'.

Here, `comment` is your controller to be used for handling the comments and `newcomment` is the function in the comment controller. In `newcomment` function, you can take the post id (37 in our example) as the parameter of the function.

You can refer to [CodeIgniter: adding parameters to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647095/codeigniter-adding-parameters-to-url) for more information.